# Oracle Apex 5.1: Interactive Grid Target Specific Cell

Tags: apex

I'm working on interactive grid in Oracle Apex 5.1. My problem is: How can I target a specific cell of their grid (not the column), using JQuery, in order to change some properties like readonly or other?

Answer (score 0):

I found some (maybe weired) kind of workaround:
In PageDesigner add every Column a unique class.
Use javascript to get the record(the row) you want to change. form the record get the unique RecordID.
Then combine both in a jquery selector to get the cell

```
 $("[data-id='AAE6TDAAFAAPTP1AAd'] .GRUND_INFRA").addClass("is-readonly")
```

with "AAE6TDAAFAAPTP1AAd" as the RecordID and "GRUND_INFRA" as the ClassId of the Column